# WSO2 RemoteUserStoreManagerService add user auto assign "Internal/everyone" role

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using RemoteUserStoreManagerService admin service to add subscribers (end application users) to WSO2 system. Web service automatically assign "Internal/everyone" role to such an user. Even if we provide a list of desired roles for user into WS function.
Can we change such behavior? Can we turn off auto-assignment or we need to use some different API for creating subscribers?
Main problem is, that "Internal/everyone" role for default has maximum system priorities, we want manually assign desired roles for subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the expected behavior that 'Internal/everyone' role get assigned to each and every user. The purpose of having this role is to assign the permissions for newly registered users (If you want the newly registered users to be capable of login and change their password etc.).

If you do not want such functionality, you remove all the permissions from this role.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You. It seams that we on some stage changes this role permissions. In clean instal of WSO2 Api Manager has no permissions in this role.